# Bootstrap button showing blue border?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I used a bootstrap template to add buttons to my site. After changing the colors of the buttons, I noticed that there is a slight blue outline on each of my buttons... I have been trying to find a way to remove this border but I'm not sure why it is there. Is there a way to remove this border?

[image]

Comment: you need to add your relevant html and css. besides guessing, how are we supposed to help if we can't see what you have done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With out seeing your code, I would suggest just applying this css to your `btn` class

```
.btn {
  border:none;
}
```

`.btn` should be used by every button styled with bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

## Use `outline:none` to remove btn border background

```
*.btn:active, .btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }
```

---

```css
   

*.btn:active, .btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
        outline: none !important;
    }





    .btn {
      margin:32px;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  

<h1 class="text-center"> Remove Border Blue Lines from Bootstrap Button </h1>
<br>

   <center> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Button</button> </center>
    
  <br>  <br>
```